# loading .dat file to SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, ssis

i have the below record sent on .dat file which has no header records, i am trying to load this to SQL server creating a new table with several column through SSIS. Please find the sample data

8145FAIRMANY UNIV UPWARD BOUND P1073 N. BENSON RD.
5509AACE GOAL SEARCH DALY CITY  1840 SUTTER ST                STE 206

8145 in the first record should be placed in column A, FAIRMANY UNIV UPWARD BOUND P in column B, 1072 N BENSON Road in Column C. SInce the record doenst have either comma or the tab all the record is being loaded in to a single column. 
i tired using saving the file to Excel but wasnt a great solution for the data i have.
Any other help will be appreciated.

Comment: sorry unable to read this text to separate column, need any delimiter for split text to column

Comment: You can either load text file by having delimiters between columns such as commas or spaces or by having fixed length width columns. I don't see either in the sample provided.

Comment: that is what i am trying to figure it out ? i have got over 40K record to be loaded to SQL server and i tired it using SSIS which didnt help. is there a way to add delimited to split these records?

Comment: without delimiter is not possible.

Comment: Benjamin, is there a way i could add the delimiter for these records ??

Comment: I have found the solution , pretty interesting ....

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21456/export-or-save-excel-files-with-pipe-or-other-delimiters-instead-of-commas/